# getting next sibling node value/text returns empty string

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

im trying to get data from some url , this url contains bunch of `h3` tags each followed by a `p` tag .... i want to loop throw h3 tags , print each one of them and jump on the next element ( p ) and print that as well .... basically i want to print `h3=>p` pairs

```
    $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $prologue = '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">';

    $doc->loadHTML($prologue.$page);
    $finder = new \DOMXPath($doc);
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'td-post-content td-pb-padding-side')]");
    $hList =  $nodes[0]->getElementsByTagName('h3');

        foreach ($hList as $k=>$h )
        {
            $text = $h->nodeValue ;
            dump( 'h3->' , $text);
            $p = $h->nextSibling ;
            dump( 'p->' , $p->nodeValue);
        }
```

here is an example link

> https://unludetay.com/2020/01/timothee-chalamet-kac-kilo-boyu-kac-nereli-kac-yasinda-sevgilisi-kimdir.html

here is my output

[image]

as you can see the p tag is an empty string for some reason , but in the source code you can see the next element(p) and its value/text

[image]

Comment: `$p = $h->nextSibling` is accessing the white space text node that exists _between_ the `h3` and the `p` elements. This is basically the same issue, as with the client-side DOM implementation in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling#notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to @CBroe comment ,  here is how i did it

```
        $hList =  $nodes[0]->getElementsByTagName('h3');

        foreach ($hList as $k=>$h )
        {
            $h_text = $h->nodeValue ;
            dump($h_text);

            $current_el = $h ;
            $current_nodeName = $current_el->nodeName ;

            while ($current_nodeName != 'p')
            {

                $current_el = $current_el->nextSibling ;
                $current_nodeName = $current_el->nodeName ;
            }

           $p_text =  $current_el->nodeValue;
            dd($p_text);
        }
```